# Google play apk publish error (multiple apk's)

Tags: android, google-play

I have published my app using multiple apk's concept (as you can see in the attached image). Now i'm trying publish update version of app. But play not allowing me to. It says "Version is not served to any device configuration". Please take a look in to the attached image for more information.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can publish an APK with the same PackageName only once. You have to change the Package Name in Your Application on Manifest and the java class that it´s name of.

So if You got multiple APKs made from one source, every APK needs it´s own Package Name.

### EDIT

If You Edit one of these APKs with unique Package Names, then You have to Update the Version Number inside the Manifest. For Example:

You have Your first App, inside Manifest, it looks similar to this:

```
    android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1"
```

If You want to Update, You have to change the versionCode and name

```
    android:versionName="1.1" android:versionCode="2"
```

And if You work with the Multiple APK Support, it´s similar. The API say:

***Each APK must have a different version code, specified by the android:versionCode attribute.**

Comment: I have already published app using multiple apk's concept (ref. http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html ). Now i'm trying to publish an updated version of the app.

Comment: You are right. And i'm already doing that. As you can see, i'm trying to publish apk with higher version code (101). But this seems something else.@Opiatefuchs

Comment: Ah, I think the Problem is, as the API says, an APK that requires a higher API level must have a higher version code. So, Your APK with version 99(2.6.46) is for API 9+, but the 101(2.6.66) is for API 7+. I think tha´s the problem...

Comment: Hmm, that make sense. So i have to unpublish or deactivate version 99(2.6.46) before publishing version 101(2.6.66) ???

Comment: I think yes, this could work. But I think the better way for the future ist, to give the highest possible number on higher API´s, so that You can update Your Apps without getting problems..

Answer (score 0):

There is a recommended version code naming pattern that will overcome exactly the issue you have. It is discussed in the [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) documentation.

It works by using a 7 digit versionCode number that includes the SDK API version prefixed as well as the actual version of your app. Here is a diagram of the version code scheme:

[image: Version scheme for different API levels]

In the example given by the OP this would allow updating of the API 7+ version without influencing the current 9+ version and would prevent the error blocking publishing of version 101. The versionCode for the two versions would now be:

- Version supporting API 7+: versionCode 0700101
- Version supporting API 9+: versionCode 0900101

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Brent Answer.

In Short ,Higher the API support application should have highest version code.

Lower API support application should have version code lesser than Higher API support application.

FYI: Make sure you are switch to Advanced mode in you Google play developer account.